# How to stop exponential value and do max digit validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying input a maximum number of digit as 16 including . and decimal number
the amount number should be max 13 and one "." and 2 decimals
for eg. 5656546355646.00 = 16 characters

**but currently its not validating and going upto display exponential value.
13 digits max, should only display whole numbers upto 2 decimal places, and should not display exponential value**

**here is my code 
script**

```
function getKeyValue(keyCode) {
    if(keyCode > 57) { //also check for numpad keys
        keyCode -= 48;
    }
    if(keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) {
        return String.fromCharCode(keyCode);
    }
}

function formatNumber(input) {
    if(isNaN(parseFloat(input))) {
        return "0.00";
    }
    var num = parseFloat(input);
    return (num / 100).toFixed(2);
}

$(".amountInput").keydown(function(e) {     
                //handle backspace key

                var input = $(this).attr("data-actual-input");
                if(e.keyCode == 8 && input.length > 0) {
                    input = input.slice(0,input.length-1); //remove last digit
                    $(this).attr("data-actual-input", input);
                    $(this).val(formatNumber(input));
                }
                else {
                    var key = getKeyValue(e.keyCode);
                    if(key) {
                        input += key; //add actual digit to the input string
                        $(this).attr("data-actual-input", input);
                        $(this).val(formatNumber(input)); //format input string and set the input box value to it
                    }
                }
                if(e.which == 8 || e.which == 46) {
                     return true;
                }
                var inpVal = $(this).val();
                if(inpVal.length > 15) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 return false;
                }
                return false;
            });
```

**html code**

```
    <input type='tel' class="form-control amountInput" name="amt" data-actual-input="" value="0.00" required>
```

***jsfiddle***

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpn1w84f/1/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the maxLength attribute? From your example:

```
<input type='tel' class="form-control amountInput" name="amt" data-actual-input="" value="0.00" maxlength="15" required>
```

Comment: maxLength works, the problem is with the keydown() function. To see this, just disable this function (returning true for example).

$(".amountInput").keydown(function(e) { 
    return true;
});